# SQL Server 2016 login language display is wrong

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Even after changing the language for a login from Arabic to us_english it doesn't save it. It continues to show Arabic. The server default language is us_english. How do I fix this. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If the change (`Alter login LoginName  with DEFAULT_LANGUAGE  = English`) applied successfully (`Commands completed successfully.`) the language must be changed though server default is `Arabic`.

However, you have to disconnect the session and connect with new session then try `select @@language`.

If you have already done so, and the problem still persist, check SQL Error log if there is any issue reported while changing language for particular login.